# DSLR with gphoto2

Tags: linux, printing, raspberry-pi, photos, 3d

I'm trying to use my Nikon D3100 DSLR camera to make timelapses of my 3D prints with Octolapse.

However, when I send the gphoto2 --capture-image command, the camera freezes and it enters in a some kind of never-ending loading state.

I'm running gphoto2 2.5.27.1 developer version. Any thoughts/ideas? Thanks

Comment: I've no idea what that app is trying to send, but the D3xxx series is generally not tetherable. You need a D5xxx minimum.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess I'll just have to use a script to end the process after the photo gets taken and live with it.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved it: https://www.reddit.com/r/octoprint/comments/o9j3y3/gphoto2_with_octoprintoctolapse/ Basically, you need to change your usb cable, format the sd card and try an earlier version of gphoto2.